# How to get only the exact list of events using the core_calendar_get_calendar_monthly_view

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

The response using this function is not ideal for getting just the events, the response will return all the data you want if you will create the UI for the calendar, I just want the response to be like the response using the `core_calendar_get_calendar_events` just the list of the events.

[image]

Just like this, but this will return all the events regardless of the date. It's not accepting `year` and `month` parameters like in `core_calendar_get_calendar_monthly_view`

I tried doing this. Is there any other way?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it. You can use `core_calendar_get_calendar_events`

https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=253940

just add these paremeters if you want to specify the date range.

`&options[timestart]=1391212800&options[timeend]=1409529599`